# Where can I find good JMeter tutorials?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have just been assigned the tasks of doing some research and doing some JMeter tests of my own to get familiar with performance testing. As I have never used this tool before, I would just like to know where I can find good JMeter tutorials for beginners?

Comment: You can check here for the beginners tips and tricks - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-tips-tricks-for-beginners/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. Looking into [JMeter User's Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) will be indeed good as first step (Getting Started, Building a Test Plan, Building a Web Test Plan).
2. Several step-by-step guidelines about JMeter setup and usage for performance/load testing you can find here:


   - JMeter articles and tutorials:

   [Load Testing your Applications with Apache JMeter](http://www.jguru.com/article/server-side/load-testing-with-apache-jmeter.html)

   [Using JMeter](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/01/15/jmeter.html)

   [Effective load testing with Apache JMeter](http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2010/09/23/effective-load-testing-with-apache-jmeter/)

   [Load Testing with JMeter: Getting Started](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2011/sep/21/load-testing-jmeter-part-1-getting-started/)

   [A Simple Load Test with JMeter](https://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/07/18/simple-load-test-with-jmeter)

   [Load Testing with Apache JMeter](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/17950)

   [Performance testing with JMeter](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2008/10/performance_testing_with_jmete/)

   [Your First JMeter Test](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=269)

   [Functional Testing with JMeter](http://www.packtpub.com/article/functional-testing-with-jmeter)

   [JMeter Resources @ InfoSec Institute](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/tag/jmeter/)

   [JMeter Tutorial @ jmeter.net](http://www.jmeter.net/)

   [JMeter Tutorial @ tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/)

   [JMeter: getting started video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI6u5pclYIw)

   [RESTful API testing with JMeter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-jmeter-restful/)


   [Blazemeter Blog](http://blazemeter.com/blog)

   [Ubik Load Pack Blog](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog)


   Some thoughts on stress testing web applications with JMeter: [part 1](http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/17/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-1/), [part 2](http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/)

   [Concurrent, High Throughput Performance Testing with JMeter](http://planet.jboss.org/post/concurrent_high_throughput_performance_testing_with_jmeter)


   - More common about load and performance testing:

   [Load, Stress, Performance Test Terms, Deliverables, Profiles and Reports](http://www.wilsonmar.com/perfrpt.htm)


   - JMeter results analysis:

   [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) - set of custom graphs in this package; some of them provide better results reporting out-of-box than jmeter's original ones;

   [JMeter Wiki: Suggestions and Recipes for Log Analysis](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/LogAnalysis)

   [Better JMeter Graphs](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/better-jmeter-graphs/)

   [Plotting your load test with JMeter](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/plotting-your-load-test-jmeter)

   [Performance Testing: Analyzing JMeter Results](http://www.datazoo.de/articles/158/performance-testing-analyzing-jmeter-results)

   [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/)

   [JMeter Result Analysis Plugin](https://github.com/afranken/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin)


   - Cloud / distributed load testing platforms:

   [flood.io](http://flood.io/)

   [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/)

   [RedLine13](http://redline13.com/)


   - Custom JMeter plugins:

   [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

   [AtlantBH Custom JMeter Components](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components/)

   [Ubik Load Pack Plugin](http://www.ubikloadpack.com/)

   [JMeter Groovy Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-groovy-sampler/)

   [JMeter Rest Sampler](https://github.com/smartrics/JMeterRestSampler)

   [JMeter REST Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-rest-sampler/)

   [JMeter RMI Plugin](https://github.com/jmibanez/jmeter-rmi-plugin)

   [JMeter Plugin for OAuth Calls](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-oauth/)

   [JMeter AMF Plugin](https://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf)

   [JMeter AMF Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-amfsampler/)

   [JMeter AMF visualizer](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-amf-visualizer/)

   [JMeter Sampler for rstatd](http://swirstatdsample.sourceforge.net/usage.html)

   [JMeter OAuth Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/)

   [MysqlCollectorPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/MysqlCollectorPlugin)

   [JMeterDBCollector](http://jmeterdbcollect.sourceforge.net/)

   [JMeterreport plugin: Nice html reports of funtional testresults](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-969)

   [JMeter JDBC Sampler](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/enhanced-jdbc-sampler-for-apache-jmeter-22/)

   [JMeter Results Analyser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstats/)

   [SNMP JMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpjmeter/)

   [JMeter SNMP Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/snmppluginjmeter/)

   [JMeter SSH Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-ssh-sampler/)


   - Integration:

   [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/)

   [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)

   [Sonar JMeter Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JMeter+Plugin)

   [Bamboo JMeter Aggregator Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JMETAGG/Bamboo+JMeter+Aggregator+Plugin)

   [Using a Load Generator in NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profile-loadgenerator.html)

   [Lightning: JMeter performance testing integration with CI infrastructure](https://github.com/automatictester/lightning)


   - Books:

   [Apache JMeter: A Practical Beginner's Guide to Automated Testing and Performance Measurement for Your Websites](http://books.google.by/books/about/Apache_JMeter.html?id=nX8oKIEvUcYC) by Emily H. Halili ([Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/apache-jmeter))

   [Performance Testing With JMeter 2.9](http://books.google.by/books?id=fpWmv3wPT64C) by Bayo Erinle ([Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/performance-testing-jmeter-29))

   [Performance Testing with JMeter, 2nd Edition](https://books.google.by/books?id=6ditCAAAQBAJ) by Bayo Erinle ([Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/performance-testing-jmeter-second-edition))

   [JMeter Cookbook](https://books.google.by/books?id=gJUeBQAAQBAJ) by Bayo Erinle ([Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/jmeter-cookbook))

   [Maîtriser JMeter. Du test de charge à Devops](https://leanpub.com/maitriser-jmeter-du-test-de-charge-a-devops) by Antonio Gomes Rodrigues, Bruno Demion (Milamber) and Philippe Mouawad ([sample @ Leanpub](https://leanpub.com/maitriser-jmeter-du-test-de-charge-a-devops/read_sample))

   [Master Apache JMeter : From load testing to DevOps](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) by Antonio Gomes Rodrigues, Bruno Demion and Philippe Mouawad ([sample @ Leanpub](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops/read_sample))

Good luck.

---

**UPD.**
Please find, use and feel free to extend this [Awesome JMeter](https://aliesbelik.github.io/awesome-jmeter/) collection continued as [github repo](https://github.com/aliesbelik/awesome-jmeter).

Comment: New link for [Load Testing your Applications with Apache JMeter](http://www.jguru.com/article/server-side/load-testing-with-apache-jmeter.html)

Comment: Alies, could you, please, add [Jmeter blog](http://blazemeter.com/blog) to list(if you find it useful)? I see, that Blazemeter is already in list, but we also have a blog. P.S. Please, do not consider my message as a SEO. Thanks.

Comment: There is also a decent book on Packt here: http://www.packtpub.com/beginning-apache-jmeter/book if you'd like to add it to your already awesome list.

Comment: I have always found it fascinating how similar JMeter is to SoapUI .

Comment: @AliaksandrBelik, I've heard reviews that the book by Emily H. Halili sucks,  have you read the book and what are your thoughts?

Comment: @Pacerier, this book is stated as "a practical beginner's guide" - and it's really too "beginner's". It got into my field of vision when I already had quite enough experience with JMeter, so I cannot say this book was useful for me.

Comment: shameless plug-in to my blog - [JMeter Tutorials](http://www.seleniumtests.com/p/performance-testing-videos.html)

Comment: I have found this [blog](http://shantonusarker.blogspot.com/p/jmeter.html) very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I have put together a really simple article of doing performance testing with Jmeter over here - http://testcy.co.in/performance-testing-jmeter. Even novice users with not much technical knowledge of code can do performance testing using this method.

For more tutorials, here you go,

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_tutorial.pdf
2. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html
3. http://www.roseindia.net/jmeter/
4. http://jmetertutorials.blogspot.in/
5. http://www.jmeter.net/

Enjoy performance testing :)

Comment: The tutorialspoint one is **really good**. I've also found another decent one at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/jmeter-tutorial-load-testing.html too.

Comment: And also a good quick overview at http://jmeter-expert.blogspot.sg/2010/03/how-apache-jmeter-simulates-multiple.html

Comment: I have also compiled a resource list for JMeter tutorials. Please take a look http://binaryclips.com/2016/02/03/jmeter-tutorials/

Comment: http://testcy.co.in/performance-testing-jmeter  link doesn't work

Comment: I guess there's some problem with the servers. Will be up and running soon!!!