# Performance testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to JMeter and I want to learn JMeter step by step. Would you suggest me the easiest ways that how can I start a performance testing using JMeter??

Thanks,

Matvey H

Comment: There are tons of tutorials. Please take a look with this: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best option to start with is JMeter official [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/).Given you read it end-to-end and execute mentioned examples to get understanding on how this or that test element works - you'll be good to go to start load testing using JMeter.

More detailed information on each Test Element can be found at [Component Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) page.

Information regarding JMeter Functions is at [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) page

I would also suggest bookmarking [The Ultimate JMeter Resource List](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ultimate-jmeter-resource-list) - the most comprehensive compilation of JMeter-related materials.