# How to start threads randomly in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I Have to run a performance test in jmeter, I got 10 threads(Scripts) having different no of users. Now I want to start 6 thread in every 5 second, Those 6 thread are random. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you want only some of your threads to be randomly started?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find good JMeter tutorials?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials)