# How to do better performance testing using JMeter for mobile application

Tags: java, jmeter, mobile, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing

I am new to JMeter, Can anyone help me to do better performance testing of mobile application and graph with different ranging. 
e.g : Thread = 10 Ramp-Up=0 Loop Count =1

The outcome is Throughput as 17.8/sec

Is this is right/wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should research performance testing. So that you can think about what you want to test and how to validate that.

Numbers are relative to what you expect, this is different for every use-case. We cannot answer if this is right or wrong.

[This answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials) has links to tutorials and suggests books to get started with JMeter and performance testing in general. After your research, you can probably ask better more specific questions.